# InnoDB returned OS error 121

Tags: mysql, windows, innodb

I got problems with my MySQL Instance running on a Windows Server 2012.

Sometimes the DB "shutdown" by itself. The Error Code which is provided in the Log files:

Windows Log:

```
InnoDB: File (unknown): 'flush' returned OS error 121. Cannot continue operation
```

MySQL Log:

```
Version: '5.6.22-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2017-03-23 04:30:04 147c  InnoDB: Operating system error number 21 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2017-03-23 04:30:04 408 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'flush' returned OS error 121. Cannot continue operation
```

If i start the MySQL Service again, it runs for about 1 day, then the error returns an the Service Stops with the error above.

Any Idea what the error means? Find no Informatoin about this specific Error.

Comment: Sounds like a mixup between file names and directory names.  Did the configuration change recently?

Comment: no, the configuration is the same since it was installed. the database runs without error for about 6 months, now the error occurs.